# Creating a bar from repeated characters in python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm creating a bar from repeated characters in python. The script takes 1 or 2 arguments. The first argument is the character to be repeated, the second argument is the number of repeats. If the second argument is omitted a default value of 85 is used. Any character is allowed, except the asterix, because this returns an error. How could the script be modified to also except an asterix as repeat character??

Here's an example output: $$$$$$$$$$$ (11 repeats of $)

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
arg_1 = sys.argv[1]

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    print(arg_1 * 85)
else:
    arg_2 = sys.argv[2]
    print(arg_1 * int(arg_2))
```

Comment: *Which* error does it return?

Comment: The error is: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10." But that's a bogus error. The true error is that you get: * * int(arg_2)) when * is the repeat character. This on the other hand would work: '*' *int(arg_2)). But how could you get the value from a variable between apostrophes. If you put 'arg_1' you get the literal arg_1 as repeat character.